# How to effectively add additional custom JQuery function to Submit Button on Forms with SilverStripe

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, silverstripe

I am using SilverStripe 3.0 with the silverstripe-userforms submodule.
This is really difficult to explain so please be patient.

I want to add a custom function (check textarea word count) to a Form, however I am unsure of how best to attach the function as I dont want to hack the core validation js files.

```
$('button[type="submit"]').entwine({
    onclick: function () {
        var $this = $('textarea.max-words');
        var wordcount = getWords($this);
        if (wordcount > maxWords) {
            if ($this.next().is("span")) {
                $('#maxwords-error').html(function () {
                    return spanText(wordcount, maxWords);
                });

            }
            else {
                $this.after(function () {
                    return "<span id='maxwords-error' class='required message'>" + spanText(wordcount, maxWords) + "</span>"
                });
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Silverstripe uses the entwine library so I have tried to do the same.

My problem is this

1. When run, the user is first prompted to complete the required word count as per the function above.
2. Once this condition is met, other additional validation be run as per the module (e.g. need to add a valid email address to the email field) form fields.
3. The user can complete the word count as per custom function, but if another part of the validation fails (e.g. the email field does not contain a valid email) the user can add an email, but then change the word count and submit successfully. Once the function is successful it never seems to run again.

How do I get my custom function to run each time the submit button is pushed, irrelevant of if the word count was correct or incorrect previously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should also cancel the click event so that it doesn't get propagated. Something like this (simplified):

```
$('button[type="submit"]').entwine({
    onclick: function (evt) {
        if(wordCountValidationFailed){
            evt.preventDefault();
            evt.stopPropagation();
            evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

This ensures that execution of the event pipeline will stop, as soon as your word-count check fails. This should prevent the submission of the form if all form fields – except the word-count – are valid.